# RavenDB index/query documents where field does not exist

Tags: lucene, ravendb

I have a collection of documents called Message. As part of a migration operation, I'm setting a timestamp on records that migrated, e.g.

```
...
new PatchRequest
{
    Type = PatchCommandType.Set,
    Name = "MigratedDateTime",
    Value = DateTime.UtcNow
},
...
```

I can create an index on the field MigratedDateTime, `MigratedDateTime:[2016-02-11 TO 2016-02-12]` but I cannot figure out how to find documents where this field is not set at all. Is this possible? If so, what would the lucene query look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an index, that index would have something like:

Migrated = doc.MigratedDateTime != null

Then you can query on Migrated:false

Comment: thanks! Can you give me an idea of how intensive the operation is? Eg. if the field in question can be large (500kb+) would it be expensive in computation and/or storage to index on whether that field is null?

Comment: It is very cheap operation, it just store the boolean

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but in RavenDB 5.0 you can just do

from tablename
group by MigratedDateTime
where MigratedDateTime != null

not sure whether it executes more efficiently, but it is much easier.